# relevanssi plugin: disable searching within words

Tags: search, wordpress

I need to disable searching within words, for example when I search word 'the' now in results it shows also 'together','other','rather',etc.. I need to search only words, not search letters within the word.

I tried to change this line from search.php in plugin files, but nothing:

```
if ("always" == $fuzzy) { 
        $o_term_cond = apply_filters('relevanssi_fuzzy_query', "(relevanssi.term LIKE '%#term#%' OR relevanssi.term_reverse LIKE CONCAT(REVERSE('#term#'), '%')) ");
    }
```

Comment: Did you ask the official support for help?

Comment: Yes no replies yet:(((, but I need to solve it ASAP @dingo_d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after many searches, I decided to change regexp for highlighting and it works:

Regexp before: `"/($pr_term)(?!(^&+)?(;))/iu"`
Regexp now: `"/\b($pr_term)\b/"`

I made changes in excerpts-highlights.php